# Access SQLIte database of an app from IntentService even if app is killed

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite, intentservice

I have an IntentService which gets triggered at a specific interval.. It performs certain tasks and update the SQLite database of the app.

It works fine when app is in foreground and background. But when the app is killed the service crashes with an NPE where I'm trying to access the database content.

So am I right in assuming that the SQLite database is not available to the IntentService once the app is killed?

Comment: What's your logcat said?

Comment: Why dont you try a background service with an Alarm Manager? This would be more efficient than polling.

Comment: I am using a background service with alarm manager.. Its an IntentService.

Comment: logcat gives null pointer exception..when I'm trying to retrieve a row from the database.

Comment: Null pointer exception? Try to provide more info

Comment: All I want to know if the SQLite database is accessible by the service when the application is killed.

Comment: I am facing issue similar issue. Do you got solution? @DeepakSenapati

Comment: Can somebody answer this question? I have got the same issue.